Creating tabs similar to the tab structure in Google with C# .net-core mcv
enter image description here
Hello friends. I'm asking for help with something.
I want to set up a structure in the asp.net core web mvc project. In fact, this structure is similar to Google's window and tab structure.
This is the structure I want. My project will have a menu and links. It dynamically transfers the content and title of the link I click to the page.
It will add it as TabControl. However, it will get the content from the separately created index.cshtml page. In this way, my layout will appear as multiple tabs instead of just the page of the link I clicked, and I can go to the page I want by clicking on the tab controller without clicking any links. .
You can look at the picture above as an example.
Thank you, best regards...
When I click on the menus on the left, I add it to the page as a tabcontrol and I can pull the page content from the index.cshtml page with Ajax, but when there is a submit and post operation in a form on the page, the layout is disrupted and a single page appears again, as only one page is returned.

You want to recreate the browser... inside the browser?   What if one of your pages in one of your tabs is your page - you'd have a browser inside a browser inside a browser???

Use iframe for the tab content so that it doesn't affect the wrapper ("browser" / tabs) page.   Some pages have frame-break-out code so won't sit well inside another page.

There is a menu on the left side of my layout. When the links in this menu are clicked, a tab belonging to the clicked link should be created in the empty space outside the menu and its content should be dynamically pulled from the link's view file with Ajax and brought to the tab content. This way I will be able to add multiple tabs from the same page or different pages on my screen.

Hi @ugurgzlks, what you have done right now? Pls share enough code that we can help you.

Hello. If you wish, I can share the project and database directly.

Hi @ugurgzlks, just share code sample which you faced the issue is enough.
